# Can I add 64bit constants to 64bit registers?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, immediate-operand

At my 64bit Intel machine following code works:

```
mov rdi, 1 << 40
add r10, rdi
```

and this quite equivalent looking one produces a warning and doesn't work:

```
add r10, 1 << 40
```

Should I just stick with number 1 or am I missing something? This behaviour seems akward.

The warning produced by code nr 2:

```
warning: signed dword immediate exceeds bounds
```

Comment: Related: [How to push a 64bit int in NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917643/how-to-push-a-64bit-int-in-nasm): if a sign-extended imm32 won't work, usually best to `mov` the constant to a register, just like for ALU instructions like `add`.

Comment: Also related [`mov r64, imm64` vs. loading it from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433208/which-is-faster-imm64-or-m64-for-x86-64).

Comment: [x86\_64 Cannot add 64 bit value to rax, "operand mismatch on 'add'"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58258882) is the GAS version of this; much less helpful error message, but does error instead of warning and encoding a wrong value.

Comment: If the value is in memory you can just do a 32-bit add to the high part: `add dword ptr [var + 4], (1 << 40) >> 32`

Comment: @PeterCordes As a side note compilers in 64 bit make use of `mov r64, disp[rip]` instead of using the `mov r64, imm64` because it is faster by about 23% (on my Xeon).

Comment: @AlexisWilke: That's not what latest trunk GCC/clang do, at least not in a trivial `return 0x123456789ab;` function when tuning for recent Intel or AMD CPUs or with the default -mtune=generic (https://godbolt.org/z/eT4jMqMEG).  I think I have seen them use memory for 64-bit constants in weird cases, but the risk is that on an L3 cache miss it's *much* slower.  But yes, if all goes well, then throughput can be higher for a mov-load from memory and for a 10-byte mov imm64, depending on how well code packed into the uop cache.  (Or if not running from the uop cache at all e.g. from JCC erratum)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an opcode for `mov r/m64, imm64`, but there is no opcode for `add r/m64, imm64` in the x86-64 instruction set. In other words: you cannot use 64-bit immediate operand for `add`, but you can for `mov` (there are many instructions that don't have the `imm64` variant; you can check the Instruction Set Reference in the Intel Software Developer Manual to check which instructions have such variant and which don't).

Comment: In fact `mov` is the *only* instruction that takes an `imm64`. 
 See [Intel's insn set ref manual entry for `mov`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/MOV).   (There's also a special AL/AX/EAX/RAX-only `moffs` form that doesn't use a regular addressing mode, and allows a 64-bit absolute address).  But `mov r64, imm64` works with any reg.