# How does RIP-relative addressing perform compared to mov reg, imm64?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86-64

It is known fact that x86-64 instructions do not support 64-bit immediate values (except for mov). Hence, when migrating code from 32 to 64 bits, an instruction like this:

```
    cmp rax, addr32
```

cannot be replaced with the following:

```
    cmp rax, addr64
```

Under these circumstances, I'm considering two alternatives: (a) using a scratch register for loading the constant or (b) using rip-relative addressing. The two approaches look like this:

```
    mov r11, addr64 ; scratch register
    cmp rax, r11
```

---

```
ptr64: dq addr64

...
     cmp rax, [rel ptr64]    ; encoded as cmp rax, [rip+offset]
```

I wrote a **very** simple loop to compare the performance of both approaches (which I paste below). While (b) uses an indirect pointer, (a) has the the immediate encoded in the instruction (which could lead to a worse usage of i-cache). Surprisingly, I found that (b) run ~10% faster than (a). Is this result something to be expected in more common real-world code?

---

```
true:  dq 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000
false: dq 0xAAAABBBBAAAABBBB

main:
    or rax, 1  ; rax is odd and constant "true" is even
    mov rcx, 0x1
    shl rcx, 30
branch:
    mov r11, 0xFFFF0000FFFF0000 ; not present in (b)
    cmp rax, r11                ; vs cmp rax, [rel true]
    je next
    add rax, 2
    loop branch

next:
    mov rax, 0
    ret
```

Comment: `mov rcx, 0x1` / `shl rcx, 30` has *zero* advantage over `mov ecx, 1<<30`.  Also, why do you want the starting value of `rax` to depend on whatever garbage the CRT startup code left in `rax`?

Comment: Yes, I know, I was just lazy and didn't want to write a very big constant and the count the zeros :). As for `rax`, I wasn't interested in its value, but in the `je next` never to get taken. Having an unpredictable initial value somehow sounded as a good property in my mind, but I guess it doesn't matter and it's just confusing.

Comment: That's why you let the assembler make the constant for you, but writing literally `mov ecx, 1<<30`.  That is valid NASM syntax: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5.4.  Also, you could have simplified this a lot by using `cmp / jnz` as the loop branch.  (And just choose your 64-bit constants so the loop runs in a reasonable amount of time.)  An extra not-taken branch inside a loop has throughput consequences for tiny loops on some CPUs.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-like-this.

Answer (score 3):

> Surprisingly, I found that (b) run ~10% faster than (a)

You probably tested on a CPU other than AMD Bulldozer-family or Ryzen, which have a fast `loop` instruction.  On other CPUs, **[`loop` is very slow, mostly on purpose for historical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently), so you bottleneck on it**.  e.g. 7 uops, one per 5c throughput on Haswell.

`mov r64, imm64` is bad for uop cache throughput because of the large immediate taking 2 slots in Intel's uop cache.  (See the Sandybridge uop cache section in [Agner Fog's microarch pdf](http://agner.org/optimize/)), and [Which is faster, imm64 or m64 for x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433208/which-is-faster-imm64-or-m64-for-x86-64) where I listed the details.

**Even apart from that, it's not too surprising that 1 extra uop in the loop makes it run slower**.  You're probably not on an AMD CPU (with single-uop / 1 per 2 clock `loop`), because the extra `mov` in such a tiny loop would make more than 10% difference.  Or no difference at all, since it's just 3 vs. 4 uops per 2 clocks, if that's correct that even tiny `loop` loops are limited to one jump per 2 clocks.

On Intel, `loop` is 7 uops, one per 5 clocks throughput on most CPUs, so the 4-per-clock issue/rename bottleneck won't be what you're hitting.  `loop` is micro-coded, so the front-end can't run from the loop buffer.  (And Skylake CPUs have their LSD disabled by a microcode update to fix the partial-register erratum anyway.)  So the `mov r64,imm64` uop has to be re-read from the uop cache every time through the loop.

---

**A load that hits in cache has very good throughput** (2 loads per clock, and **in this case micro-fusion means no extra uops to use a memory operand instead of register for `cmp`**).  So the main penalty in using a constant from memory is the extra cache footprint and cache misses, but your microbenchmark won't reveal that at all.  It also has no other pressure on the load ports.

---

### In the general case:

**If possible, use a RIP-relative `lea` to generate 64-bit address constants.

e.g. `lea rax, [rel addr64]`.**  Yes, this takes an extra instruction to get the constant into a register.  (BTW, just use `default rel`.  You can use `[abs fs:0]` if you need it.

You can avoid the extra instruction if you **build position-dependent code** with the default (small) code model, **so static addresses fit in the low 32 bits of virtual address space and can be used as immediates**.  (Actually low 2GiB, so sign or zero extending both work).  See [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) if gcc complains about absolute addressing; `-pie` is enabled by default on most distros.  This of course doesn't work in Linux shared libraries, which only support text relocations for 64-bit addresses.  But you should avoid relocations whenever possible by using `lea` to make position-indepdendent code.

Most integer build-time constants fit in 32 bits, so you can use `cmp r64, imm32` or `cmp r32, imm32` even in PIC code.

If you do need a 64-bit non-address constant, try to hoist the `mov r64, imm64` out of a loop.  Your `cmp` loop would have been fine if the `mov` wasn't inside the loop.  x86-64 has enough registers that you (or the compiler) can usually avoid reloads inside inner-most loops in integer code.

Comment: Related: [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012) / [How do RIP-relative variable references like "\[RIP + \_a\]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54745872)