# x86_64 Cannot add 64 bit value to rax, "operand mismatch on 'add'"

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, immediate-operand

I am trying to assemble some 64-bit code and the assembling fails on the line:

```
addq $0xffffff7fc0005000, %rax
```

with the error:

> Error operand type mismatch for `add'

The first operand is a 64-bit value and the latter a register which should assemble fine. This instruction is preceded by a `.code64` pseudo-op. I am assembling with

```
x86_64-elf-as test.s -o test.o --64
```

As for the assembler itself, when called with `--version` it returns:

```
GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.32
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or later.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
This assembler was configured for a target of `x86_64-elf'.
```

Comment: huh, that's a confusing error message vs. a warning for an out-of-range / not-encodeable immediate.  I'd call that a usability bug.  They could easily have written an error message that wouldn't have sent you off to SO to ask a question about it.

Comment: I'm jus curious. Do you happen to be writing a 64-bit OS with a higher half kernel?

Comment: I ask because previously you asked a question about ensuring something was 0x200 bytes in size. AT the time I believed you might have been writing a custom bootloader. In this question I noticed you are using a cross compiler version of binutils. Something I found interesting is that addq `$0xffffff7fc0005000` almost looks like what someone would do if they were writing a higher half kernel with the kernel in the last 2GiB of virtual address space. If that were true then `addq $0xffffff7fc0005000` is wrong and likely should have been the canonical address `$0xffffffffc0005000`

Comment: You wouldn't have gotten an error with `addq $0xffffffffc0005000, %rax` since `$0xffffffffc0005000` can be represented as a 32 bit signed value `$0xc0005000` which when sign extended to 64-bits is also `$0xffffffffc0005000`. (Bit 31 the top most bit of 0xc0005000 is the value 1 so when sign extended all the bits in the 64-bit value take on the value 1).

Comment: [Can I add 64bit constants to 64bit registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20020589) is the NASM version of the same question.  (NASM has a better error message: `warning: signed dword immediate exceeds bounds`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The first operand is a 64bit value and the latter a register which should assemble fine.

It shouldn't, the 64bit version of `add` can take an 8bit or 32bit sign-extended immediate, but not a 64bit immediate, which in general is rare in x64. This can be verified by looking in the Intel Software Developer's Manual or various other places, such as [this online copy of the ADD lemma](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/add).

**The only instruction that can take a full 64-bit immediate (not 32-bit sign-extended) is `mov`.** (Or `movabs` as GAS likes to call this variant, although with a large numeric constant `mov $0x123456789abc, %rcx` [will pick the necessary encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315803/difference-between-movq-and-movabsq-in-x86-64), not truncate the number).

Normally you'd `mov` a 64-bit immediate into a register and then use that.

Another option is to put the value in memory and use it in an `add` with a memory operand.