# Invalid operand for instruction

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86-64

I'm using inline x64 assembly with Intel Compiler and I'm trying to add a huge value to the RBP register.
The compiler gives me an error saying that the operand is incorrect for that huge number. Is there a way to solve this?

My code:

```
__asm add rbp, 0x7ffffffffffffff0
__asm and rbp, 0x7fffffff
```

The compiler outputs this:

> ```
> ld-link: : error : ld-temp.o <inline asm>:2:2: invalid operand for instruction
>            add rbp, 3264300659
>            ^
> ```

Comment: Similar to [Can I add 64bit constants to 64bit registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20020589/555045) with a different assembler, but `add r64, imm64` is still not encodeable.

Comment: Would you mind *not* adding a huge value to `rbp`? It is possible to do it, but the `and` instruction right after it makes that unnecessary *in this specific case* (the result can equivalently be computed with just `ebp` and 32-bit constants, which are encodeable).

Comment: It's kind of misleading to write `0x7fffffff` lined up with the most-significant digit of `0x7ffffffffffffff0`.  You should indent it more to its low digit lines up with the value you're adding, making harold's point more obvious, that you're zeroing all bits above bit#30, so that might as well be `and ebp, 0x7fffffff`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no opcode that can do it in that way!
However there is a single opcode that can do the following:

```
BigConstant = 0x7ffffffffffffff0
...
...
add   rbp, qword ptr BigConst  //48 03 2D xx xx xx xx
```

You could also use an extra register to solve the problem, like:

```
mov   rax, 0x7ffffffffffffff0
add   rbp, rax
```