# Why "push qword imm64" isn't allowed on x64?

Tags: assembly, stack, push, x86-64

I really don't see any logical/technical reason for prohibiting it. AFAIK, an imm64 fits just nicely on a 64-bit stack, alignment aside.

Comment: Because engineers at AMD designed the instruction set that way. It's a good question but (probably) a bad match for this website, where questions that can be answered more objectively are preferred.

Comment: In x86_64 the only instruction that allows 64-bit immediate is movabs. You can only push 32-bit immediates

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: can you retag this with `[assembly]` so I can dup-hammer it to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917643/how-to-push-a-64bit-int-in-nasm, please?  If I edit the tags myself I the one-vote duplcate close doesn't work.

Comment: @PeterCordes done

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: thanks.