# syscall use in shellcode

Tags: assembly, x86-64, shellcode

I am learning assembly and I wrote this shellcode which is supposed to open the Google homepage on firefox. However it doesn't do anything (and even segfaults at the end because of an added instruction `add %al,(%rax)` which I don't understand), do I do things right ? I am actually not even sure I encoded the strings correctly. Thanks !

```
global _start

_start:
xor rax, rax
push rax

;https:////www.google.com
push 0x6d6f632e656c676f
push 0x6f672e7777772f2f
push 0x2f2f3a7370747468

mov rcx, rsp

push 0x786f66657269662f ; /firefox
push 0x6e69622f7273752f ; /usr/bin

mov rdi, rsp

push rax
push    rcx
push    rdi
mov     rsi, rsp

; execve
mov     al, 0x3b
syscall
```

I test my code with :

```c
char code[] = \x48\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x6f\x67\x6c\x65\x68\x2f\x2f\x77\x77\x68\x68\x74\x74\x70\x48\x89\xe1\x68\x2f\x66\x69\x72\x68\x2f\x75\x73\x72\x48\x89\xe7\x50\x51\x57\x48\x89\xe6\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05
int main(int argc, char **argv){
   (*(void(*)()) code)();
   return 0;
}`
```

Comment: Are you sure the pushes are correct? As far as I'm concerned, there is no `push imm64` in amd64 assembly.

Comment: `add %al,(%rax)` is how `00 00` decodes.  It means execution went past your code into padding.  It also means you didn't use GDB's `set disassembly-flavor intel` to match your NASM code.  BTW, @fuz is correct, there is no `push imm64`.  This code is doomed to failure; you should have gotten warnings from NASM about truncating values too large to fit: [How to push a 64bit int in NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16917643)

Comment: You're right, I changed the code to go through a register to do the all the "push"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a null terminator on the `firefox` path. Add a `push rax` before the `firefox` hex just like you did with `google.com`.

Also, to make sure you don't crash due to the lack of an `envp` variable (i.e. a random `rdx`), add this line when constructing `rsi`

```
...
push    rax
mov     rdx, rsp # Add this to set rdx = [null]
push    rcx
...
```

This passes in an empty array to `envp` through the `rdx` register.

Finally: Normally the `push rax` is a hack to get past null & newline blocked string inputs. If you're just calling it within your own c code, you can use `push 0` instead of `push rax` and forget the top line `xor` (Using `mov rax, 0x3b` for the syscall). You can leave it as-is. This was just a note.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I just figured out that the problem was due to the random rdx, it's working now