# Are these push r16 encodings correct under 64BIT mode?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel, machine-code, instruction-encoding

About push wordregister(r16) under 64BIT mode of Intel x86_64 CPU.

In B-28, Vol. 2D,
APPENDIX B, INSTRUCTION FORMATS AND ENCODINGS,
Intel Combined Manual PDF,
Order Number: 325462-080US, June 2023.

Table B-15. General Purpose Instruction Formats and Encodings for 64-Bit Mode (Contd.)
[image]

I think the correct one is 0110_0110 (0x66). But it is 0101_0101 (0x55).
0x66 is an operand-size prefix that changes operand-size to 16 bits where cpu is in 64-bit mode.
But I don't know 0x55 prefix.

Additionally, there is no push imm64 instruction,
according to
[How to push a 64bit int in NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917643/how-to-push-a-64bit-int-in-nasm).

[image]

Comment: Right, the encoding for `push ax` in 64-bit mode is `66h 50h`.  `55h` is the opcode for `push rbp`.  Intel's manuals are notoriously imperfect, you might want to report these defects to Intel (probably on their forums) for them to update.